# Backbone with custom rest endpoints

Tags: rest-api, nonce, backbone

I have created a custom endpoint that returns select user meta data. I am trying to access this endpoint with Backbone. It works as expected in Postman and from my Backbone/javascript script If I have my access check dummied out.

```
var app2 ={};

app2.Pilot = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'pilotdata/v1/pilot/'
 });

 app2.pilot = new app2.Pilot();

 app2.pilot.fetch(
   {data: ({ id: 1 })}
 ).then(function(){
    console.log(app2.pilot)
})
```

Of course can't have the data hanging out naked. So I implement my access check and I get a status Unauthorized returned as expected. As the nonce is not being returned. But how to set the nonce? from [theAverageDev](https://www.theaveragedev.com/wp-rest-api-nonce-authentication/) I can up with:

```
    var app2 ={};

    app2.Pilot = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'pilotdata/v1/pilot/',
    sync: function(){
        Backbone.sync('create', this,{
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-NONCE', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
            },
        });
    },
 });

 app2.pilot = new app2.Pilot();

 app2.pilot.fetch(
   {data: ({ id: 1 })}
 ).then(function(){
    console.log(app2.pilot)
})
```

And I admit I do not fully understand what that is doing. Overriding sync? However when I do that I get

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'app2.pilot.fetch(
       {data: ({ id: 1 })}`

It appears that overriding sync undefined fetch? What is the best way to use Backbone to pass the nonce?

*I think I got it:*

```
var app2 ={};

app2.Pilot = Backbone.Model.extend({    
    url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'pilotdata/v1/pilot/',
 });

 app2.pilot = new app2.Pilot();
 app2.pilot.fetch(
  { 
   beforeSend : function(xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-NONCE', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce);
   },  
   data: ({id: 1})
   }
 ).then(function(){
    console.log(app2.pilot)
})
```

Comment: I think I have found a partial solution if I change the code such

Comment: Yes, but do try your original code with the modification as in my answer. It should work, unless your REST endpoint doesn't return a valid data.. :) Let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://backbonejs.org/#Sync):

1. **Backbone.sync** is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses `jQuery.ajax` to make a RESTful JSON request and returns a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).
2. The **sync** function may be overridden globally as `Backbone.sync`, or at a finer-grained level, by adding a `sync` function to a Backbone collection or to an individual model.

So the code you initially have is actually good, but you should `return` the `Backbone.sync()` result like so:

```js
app2.Pilot = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'pilotdata/v1/pilot/',
  sync: function( method, model, options ){
    return Backbone.sync(method, this, jQuery.extend( options, {
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-NONCE', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
      },
    } ));
  },
});
```

Secondly, you should just pass the same `method` that Backbone passes to your model's custom `sync()` function, just as you can see above. And although you don't have to, I also use `jQuery.extend()` to extend the `options` object that's passed to that `sync()` function.

And with your other approach where you pass the header when you call your model's `fetch()` function, it does work, but extending the `sync()` function is much better since you don't need to specify the header for each request. :)

Comment: Thank You, works great. So, JQuery.extend is merging the nonce header with 'other' options and then passing it to .sync? I tried not using $.extend and I can't get it to work. Nonce is passed, but  I get a null object back.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, `jQuery.extend()` merges the options and they're passed to `Backbone.sync()`. And yes, sorry, the options need to be merged before they're passed to `Backbone.sync()`. But you don't have to use `jQuery.extend()` - you can use a native JS method like `{ ...options, new_item: 'value' }` to extend the options object ..